# online document editing system implementation ideas

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a question for help, thank you for taking the time to read my question. This is my first question.

I want to write a document generation Web project and technically I plan to use vue+java+mysql

The first page of the project: the left side for multiple input boxes can be dragged up and down the input box. On the right is the document template that displays the input and changes position as the text box is dragged

2. And can download documents, store document content, files.

The question I encountered was: what technique should I use to implement the template?

I checked a lot. I also asked chatGPT. The general content is to use Handlebars and other template engines, but Handlebars does not have a ready-made template, maybe I did not find it, I want some ready-made templates, can be directly introduced, I modify the need to change the place can be.

Finally, thank you for your patience. It's my first time asking questions. I'm a little rusty. I saw this website, https://www.jobseeker.com/app/home is really inspired me, want to write a copy of its function